# Can a vertical bar be used as part of an identifier in Racket?

Tags: racket

I would like to define a variable in Racket for a quantum state, which is written by convention as:

[image: foo+bar]

The [Reader reference](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html?q=reader) tells me this is not possible, because:

> `|` starts a subsequence of characters to be included verbatim in the delimited sequence

However, I am surprised to find that page ["Special characters" in Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Special_characters#Racket), in section "Racket", mentions:

> Vertical bars can be used as identifier quotations used around it

Is this a bad formulation or can a variable name in Racket actually use a vertical bar somehow? Can someone give an example, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an alternative to `|0>`  you could use `/0>` which almost looks the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vertical bar is a way of avoiding the usual interpretation of the characters inside it from the language reader. So it can be used to define symbols with special characters inside them, for instance:

```
(define |(| 5)

(+ |(| 1)  ;   produces 6
```

You can always use the backquote to insert a vertical bar in a symbol (see the [manual](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html?q=delimiters%20and%20dispatch#%28part._default-readtable-dispatch%29)), for instance you could write the symbol `\|0>` and this would be interpreted internally as `|0>`. But in the source files you will have to use always  `\|0>` and not `|0>`. Or, to avoid this, you could change the standard reader with an [extension](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-reader.html).

But I think there is no simple way of using a symbol with a vertical bar like `|0>` in “standard” Racket, since the vertical bar is treated in special way by its reader.

Comment: Yes, that is what I understand from the first quote in my question. But it seems that precisely the only symbol that can't be included in-between vertical bars is a vertical bar :)  Is there a way around this conundrum?

Comment: I have modified the answer.

Comment: It is a bit ugly to have to refer to the variable as `\|0>`, but it seems it is the only way, indeed. Thank you!

Comment: Just for fun, I implemented a reader extension that does exactly that: https://github.com/AlexKnauth/no-vert-bar-lang

Comment: @AlexKnauth : excellent, indeed! This solves completely the problem of logc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `|` [u+007C], you could use `ǀ` [u+01c0] or `׀` [u+05c0] or `∣` [u+2223] or `❘` [u+2758].

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, I didn't know of that either. With some quick experimentation this is what I found out when you define some variables and then call them in the REPL of DrRacket:

```
(define a|| 3)
(define |b| 2)
(define ||c 5)
(define ||||d 7)
(define f|d| 9)

> a||
3
> a
3
> |b|
2
> d
7
> |d|
7
> f||d
9
> fd
9
```

`(define |e 8)` or `(define |e|| 1)` for example you get an error:

> Module Language: invalid module text . . read: unbalanced `|'

And if you want to do

```
(define ||||d 5)
(define |d| 9)
```

You get an error as well:

> module: duplicate definition for identifier in: d

So you just have to use an even number of `|` and all other characters must not be the same and you are ready to go.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to `define ||0>|` but this didn't work, because of imbalanced `|` error as you mention.